# How to split whole pandas DataFrame to list and select nth element

Tags: python, pandas

I want to slipt elements in pandas DataFrame and have specific element:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'name':
                ["0;0;*;1;1...1...1;1;*;1;1","0;0;*;1;1...1...1;1;*;1;2"],
              'name2':
                ["0;0;*;1;1...1...1;1;*;1;3","0;0;*;1;1...1...1;1;*;1;4"]})
>>> print(df)
                    name                      name2
0  0;0;*;1;1...1...1;1;*;1;1  0;0;*;1;1...1...1;1;*;1;3
1  0;0;*;1;1...1...1;1;*;1;2  0;0;*;1;1...1...1;1;*;1;4
```

Spliting with "." to list works well:

```
>>> print(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(".")))
                            name                              name2
0  [0;0;*;1;1, , , 1, , , 1;1;*;1;1]  [0;0;*;1;1, , , 1, , , 1;1;*;1;3]
1  [0;0;*;1;1, , , 1, , , 1;1;*;1;2]  [0;0;*;1;1, , , 1, , , 1;1;*;1;4]
```

For some reason not so well with "..." (which is substring actually present):

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split("...")))
              name                name2
0  [, , , , , , , , 1]  [, , , , , , , , 3]
1  [, , , , , , , , 2]  [, , , , , , , , 4]
```

Does anybody knows why?

But the main problem is that I do not know how to get specific element from the list. This gies only specific row:

```
>>> print(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(".")[0]))
name     [0;0;*;1;1, , , 1, , , 1;1;*;1;1]
name2    [0;0;*;1;1, , , 1, , , 1;1;*;1;3]
dtype: object
```

This approach would work if I process Dataframe by column:

```
>>> print(df["name"].apply(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1]))
0    1;1;*;1;1
1    1;1;*;1;2
Name: name, dtype: objec
```

I thought that processing all at once would be more efficient and cleaner?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `applymap` with a `lambda` that utilizes the `str` method `split`.  This one way to avoid being interpreted as regex.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('...'))

                        name                      name2
0  [0;0;*;1;1, 1, 1;1;*;1;1]  [0;0;*;1;1, 1, 1;1;*;1;3]
1  [0;0;*;1;1, 1, 1;1;*;1;2]  [0;0;*;1;1, 1, 1;1;*;1;4]
```

---

And to reference the first element of the split

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('...')[0])

        name      name2
0  0;0;*;1;1  0;0;*;1;1
1  0;0;*;1;1  0;0;*;1;1
```

Answer (score 2):

## First Problem:

It is because `.` is a special `regex` character. You can escape it using `\`:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split("\.\.\."))
                        name                      name2
0  [0;0;*;1;1, 1, 1;1;*;1;1]  [0;0;*;1;1, 1, 1;1;*;1;3]
1  [0;0;*;1;1, 1, 1;1;*;1;2]  [0;0;*;1;1, 1, 1;1;*;1;4]
```

## Second problem:

Use `str` again to index:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(".").str[0])
        name      name2
0  0;0;*;1;1  0;0;*;1;1
1  0;0;*;1;1  0;0;*;1;1
```

Comment: This answer is better because it explains **why** OP's problem was occurring.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that `applymap` changed the behaviour in the way you showed, +1 for that already!

Comment: `applymap` is just a raw *do this thing on all my cells!*

Comment: Thanks. I thought I tried solution for the second and got some error.